# Excel recording in Loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I am trying to do a Performace test on Excel based application with loadrunner. Started of running the protocol advisor. which is trowing error.

My main target is to record the excel based application. For simulation created a database and calling database from excel.

Any sugestions what protocol to use. Or any other tools for conducting performance test on excel based application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where the foundation classes of knowledge on development and architecture come into play for a performance test professional.

Tell us about the next upstream component from excel?   Is it connecting directly to the database or is it going through a web services or other application server layer?   Do you have SQL Queries you are trying to reproduce or some other mechanism so as accessing your source?

What have you tried?  (Other than protocol confuser?)

Comment: Excel is directly connected to SQL.Funcationality is retreiveing data from backend.

Comment: Record an ODBC virtual user using your queries and the MSQUERY application which ships as a part of Microsoft Office